# Looking for pip command that does self diagnostics

Tags: python, pip, pypi

Home Brew has the `brew doctor` command for self diagnostic and recommend fixes such as checking and granting permissions of required directories.

For example:

```
$ brew doctor

Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: The following directories are not writable by your user:
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/etc
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/share
/usr/local/share/doc

You should change the ownership of these directories to your user.
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin /usr/local/etc /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/share /usr/local/share/doc

And make sure that your user has write permission.
  chmod u+w /usr/local/bin /usr/local/etc /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/share /usr/local/share/doc
```

Does `pip` have an equivalent command for self diagnostics and recommend fixes?

Comment: pip has the capability to install packages into your home directory, so it doesn't necessarily need `/usr/local/` to be writable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a command for `pip` (but I don't think as comprehensive as `brew doctor`) which lists outdated versions of installed packages and the latest available ones which is helpful in the cases where you:

- might have to isolate a problem before it arises
- or because you suspect there might be a dependency issue
- or just being extra careful so other things don't break and want to see if there are any reported issues for that version

```
python -m pip list --outdated
```

Comment: There is also `pip check` that can be helpful. And of course `pip debug` as well.